# How execution plan works in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I've a situation where I need to write same data in two different tables after completion of all transformations.

Process is something like:

1. Reading from sources
2. Applying transformations
3. Writing in `TableA`

Now, I want to write same data in `TableB` too, with slight change in partition (e.g. removing some partition I used while writing in `TableA`).

So If I do that, will step 1 and 2 happen again while writing for `TableB` once writing in `TableA` is completed?

What's an efficient way of doing it?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi! Please add some example code: the answer will depend on what code you're talking about.

Answer (score 1):

An execution plan is the set of operations executed to translate a query language statement to a set of optimized logical and physical operations that are represented by a DAG.

And in Spark we have an optimizer named the Catalyst and it's goal is to produce automatically the most effective way to process your query.

I recommend you to do research about DAG, Catalyst, logical and physical plan...

For you case, i think you'll have something like this:

```
val secondStepResults = {
//do the step 2 transformations
//and to the persist here in order to save the dataframe in memory/disk depending on the use case and cluster configurations
}
```

save to tableA

```
secondStepResults
   .write
   .mode(saveMode)
   .saveAsTable("TableA")
```

Apply changes to your partitions from step two results

```
val secondStepResultsAfterChanges = secondStepResults
   .map(df => process(df))
```

Save to tableB

```
secondStepResultsAfterChanges 
   .write
   .mode(saveMode)
   .saveAsTable("TableB")
```